# Failed to load API definition swagger + Swashbuckle .net 6 when annotation is present

Tags: .net, swagger

I have an error when I put `[ProducesResponseType]` annotation to my POST method in .net 6
Im using Swashbuckle nuget addon for swagger documentation.
xml tags works for other methods.
When I remove this annotation, then swagger loads correctly.
What can be the cause here?

```
/// <summary>
/// Send Vat Recording Indivivual
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// Sample Request
/// 
///     POST
///     {
///      "documentNumber": "300720221231",
///      "calculationNumber":2424524588001,
///      "relatedPartyIdentifier":"test555",
///      "documentType": "Invoice",
///      "foreignDocument":false,
///      "vatAmount": 110,
///      "year": 2022
///     }
/// </remarks>
/// <response code="200">Api key has been saved into db successfully</response>
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(Result<VatRecordingIndividualResponseDto>), 200)]
[Route(nameof(VatRecordingIndividual))]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> VatRecordingIndividual([FromBody] VatRecordingIndividualRequestDto request, [FromQuery] long apiKeyId, [FromQuery] string? vatId)
{
  var response = await Mediator.Send(new CreateVatRecordingIndividualCommand { Model = request, ApiKeyId = apiKeyId, IndividualVatId = vatId });
  return StatusCode((int)response.StatusCode, response);
}
```

Comment: What does the error you get say?

Comment: Fetch error
response status is 500 https://localhost:7030/swagger/v1/swagger.json

Comment: And what does the output of the backend say?